# VSCode Extension won't run after packaging

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, rollup

I am working a simple VSCode extension that scan the currently active open file for any comments containing "//TODO: " and displays a list in a webview sidebar tab with all TODO comments in a file.

I have a working prototype which works as it should when I run it using the debugger in VSCode but as soon as I try to package it using vsce package and then install the .vsix file the sidebar icon appears and opens the sidebar but it does not scan the file ( or maybe it does but just doesn't show it) since I'm installing the extension and not debugging it, there is no way for me to track what it is doing.

Source code is in a github repo: https://github.com/bibaswan-bhawal/VSCode-TODO-List

I should mention I have confirmed all NodeJS dependency packages are installed.

output of `vsce package` command
[image]

Comment: you can add `console.log` statements and look at the developer tools console of VSC to see what happens

Comment: what is the use of committing `vsc-extension-quickstart.md` and `package-lock.json`. It is confusing to name the `ViewContainer` `xxxx-view`, because the `ViewContainer` contains `View`s

Comment: This is my first vscode extension so my naming is kind sketchy as for the vsc-extension-quickstart.md, I didnt really delete any of the starter files but Ill remove it now.

Comment: console.logging doesn't do anything when you install an extension using vsix it only works in while debugging and the extension works as it should while debugging anyways.

Comment: no the `console.log` work you just have to pen the correct Developer tools (Help > Developer Tools)

Comment: Why post images of terminal TEXT, just copy paste, it is very hard to do a text search in images

Comment: Oh didn't know about the help>developer tools I will keep that in mind for future problems. As for this one I fixed it. It was just a case of a folder getting excluded from the packaging section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error! Even though all the files were being compiled the svelte files were being compiled to out/compiled and .vscodeignore by default ignores anything in the the out folder so removing it from the file worked.